# collapse subtotals to level 2 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

does anyone know how to use VBA to collapse subtotals (once created) to level 2 so I only see the summary?

Answer (score 2):

found out from Mf excel archive question -

ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 2

simple when you know how...